# How to Add a Calculated Value to Export to Excel Function

Tags: coldfusion, export, export-to-excel

I have a block of code that sets an "Aging" value for an invoice, as part of  an export to excel script. I have all the other options in the export function working, except the "Aging" value.

Here is the SQL code for how "Aging" works:

```
<cfif Aging neq "">
<cfswitch expression="#Aging#">
   <cfcase value=29>
   AND I.DueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-29, 0) AND dateadd(day,    datediff(day, 0 ,getdate()), 0)
   AND I.OutstandingAmount > 0
  </cfcase>
   <cfcase value=59>
   AND I.DueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-59, 0) AND dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-30, 0)
AND I.OutstandingAmount > 0
</cfcase>
<cfcase value=89>
AND I.DueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-89, 0) AND dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-60, 0)
AND I.OutstandingAmount > 0
</cfcase>
<cfcase value=90>
AND I.DueDate < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-90, 0)
AND I.OutstandingAmount > 0
</cfcase>
</cfswitch>
</cfif>
```

I'm new to ColdFusion and I just cannot figure out how to write the code for the Excel part. Here is the export function, with line breaks added for readability only.

```
<!--- ------------------------------------------ --->
   <cfelseif ExType eq "xls5">
<!--- ------------------------------------------ --->
  <cfset tabchar = Chr(9)>
  <cfset NewLine = Chr(13) & Chr(10)>
  <cfcontent type="text/msexcel">
  <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="Attachment; filename=Late/Aging.xls">
  <cfoutput>DATE INVOICED#TabChar#INVOICE#TabChar#CLIENT#TabChar#TOTAL#TabChar#AMOUNT DUE#TabChar#AGE#NewLine#</cfoutput>
  <cfoutput query="viewinvoices">
    <cfif curr.currencytype eq "Euro">
      <cfset TotalC =   #LSEuroCurrencyFormat(TotalCost, "local")#>
    <cfelse>
      <CFSET oldlocale = SetLocale(#curr.currencytype#)>
      <cfset TotalC = #LSCurrencyFormat(TotalCost, "local")#>
    </cfif>  
    <cfif curr.currencytype eq "Euro">
       <cfset OutAmt = #LSEuroCurrencyFormat(OutstandingAmount, "local")#>
    <cfelse>
       <CFSET oldlocale = SetLocale(#curr.currencytype#)>
       <cfset OutAmt = #LSCurrencyFormat(OutstandingAmount, "local")#>
    </cfif>
    #DateFormat(InvoiceDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')##TabChar#
    <cfif curr.CustomInvoices eq "0">
       #Invoice#
    <cfelse>
         #NumberFormat(InvoiceCustom, '0000')#
    </cfif>
    #TabChar##Client##TabChar##TotalC##TabChar##OutAmt##TabChar##Aging##Newline#
  </cfoutput>
```

I have this in my export statement but does not seem to work:

```
<cfif Aging eq "29">
    <cfset Aging = 'Year(s)'>
<cfelseif Aging eq "59">
    <cfset Aging = 'Day(s)'>
<cfelseif Aging eq "89">
    <cfset Aging = 'Month(s)'>
<cfelseif Aging eq "90">
    <cfset Aging = 'Quarter(s)'>
<cfelse>
    <cfset Aging = 'n/a'>
</cfif>
```

The text years, etc is just for testing.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does the code that you supplied, which appears to be setting conditions for a SQL statement, have to do with exporting to Excel?

Comment: I already have the export function written but I cant figure out how to get "Aging" to appear on the excel sheet, It is just a blank column and the code above is where the aging is created, Like I said new to CF and cant seem to figure this out. I will add the export function.

Comment: So you are just trying to include the value of `Aging` (29, 59, 89 or 90) in the spreadsheet or is the `Aging` variable being returned in your query results? I don't see anything obvious in the code that you have shared but I also cannot tell where the snippets are in relation to one another.

Comment: Yes that way it will show the aging on the spreadsheet.

Comment: And the variable `Aging` is not being set again between your `<cfif>` code block and the `<cfoutput>` block that generates the formatted data? Try removing the `()` from your strings. Those may be messing with the conversion to Excel.

Comment: *I have this in my export statement but does not seem to work:* Exactly where is that code in relation to the query loop (inside the loop, before, after...)? CF code executes sequentially, so we need to see your actual code - **in order** - to understand the results you are getting. Also, what exactly is the source of this "Aging" variable? You appear to be using it before the query results are even generated, suggesting it may be a FORM/URL variable..? Can you elaborate on where it comes from and how are you using it (in plain English, not code).